# Definition of disconnected set in topology

Tags: general-topology, definition, connectedness

I'm reading through wikipedia for a rigorous definition of disconnected topological space, which is the same as the one given by Munkres.

> A topological space $X$ is said to be **disconnected** if it is the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets. Otherwise, $X$ is said to be **connected**.

The question is: does the bit "*if it is the union of two disjoint non empty open sets*" mean that the family of open sets defining the topology on $X$ cannot be partitioned into two disjoint non empty open set? Or maybe more specifically that if I take an open set $\cal{O}_1$ and an open set $\cal{O}_2$ the union of these is not $X$?

Comment: the latter; the former doesn't make sense (how is a family partitioned into two sets?)

Comment: A family is set of sets, two sub-families can form a partition.

Comment: disconnected means you can find two disjoint non-empty open sets (in the topology) whose union is the space; you're partitioning the space, not the topology

Comment: If the topological *space* is $(X,\tau_X)$ where $\tau_X$ is the family of open sets with the known properties. When you say space you mean $X$, right?

Comment: Right, sometimes we are imprecise and conflate the space with the underlying set

Comment: Is there a theorem that relates homeomorphisms to connectdness?

Comment: That's a different question, but homeomorphisms map connected sets to connected sets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94987/discussion-between-user8469759-and-j-w-tanner).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set with topology $\tau$.

$X$ is disconnected if there exist two disjoint non-empty open sets (elements of $\tau$) whose union is $\pmb X$.

This is not about partitioning $\tau.$